# Leaflet checking and disabling GeoJSON sublayers troubleshoots

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geojson

I have been fighting with the GeoJSON sublayers in leaflet map.

The problem is, that when I switch them off, they still appear, when change the zoom level
In this event I cannot even switch them off as per in the image below:

[image]

Once I only click on the job thick, then console says:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_targets' of null
>       at NewClass.removeInteractiveTarget (Layer.js:83)
>       at NewClass._removePath (SVG.js:132)
>       at NewClass.onRemove (Path.js:90)
>       at NewClass.removeLayer (Layer.js:185)
>       at NewClass.eachLayer (LayerGroup.js:121)
>       at NewClass.onRemove (LayerGroup.js:109)
>       at NewClass.removeLayer (Layer.js:185)
>       at NewClass.removeFrom (Layer.js:66)
>       at NewClass.remove (Layer.js:59)
>       at NewClass.onRemove (leaflet.markercluster.js:1)

Before I start to write my code, see my JS fiddle here:

https://jsfiddle.net/Krukarius/abnkfxcL/3/

And the map demo here:

https://mariusz-krukar.mkrgeo.pl/en/workshop/media/MDU_demo.html

Now my existing code:

```
  document.querySelector("input[name=vm]").addEventListener('change',  function() {   //main geoJSON layer
  if(this.checked) {
if (!map.hasLayer(job2)) map.removeLayer(job2);
if (!map.hasLayer(infill)) map.addLayer(infill);
if (!map.hasLayer(mdu)) map.addLayer(mdu);
if (!map.hasLayer(featuresLayer2)) map.addLayer(featuresLayer2);
//document.querySelector("input[name=vm]").disabled
document.querySelector("input[name=infill]").disabled = false;
document.querySelector("input[name=mdu]").disabled = false;
document.querySelector("input[name=infill]").checked = true;
document.querySelector("input[name=mdu]").checked = true;
}
else {
if (map.hasLayer(job2)) map.removeLayer(job2);
if (map.hasLayer(infill)) map.removeLayer(infill);
if (map.hasLayer(mdu)) map.removeLayer(mdu);
if (map.hasLayer(featuresLayer2)) map.removeLayer(featuresLayer2);
document.querySelector("input[name=infill]").disabled = true;
document.querySelector("input[name=mdu]").disabled = true;
document.querySelector("input[name=infill]").checked = false;
document.querySelector("input[name=mdu]").checked = false;
}
});

 document.querySelector("input[name=infill]").addEventListener('change', function() {   //GeoJSOn sublayer1
 if(this.checked) {
  if (!map.hasLayer(infill)) map.addLayer(infill);
  //if (!map.hasLayer(job2)) map.addLayer(job2);
  //if (!map.hasLayer(featuresLayer2)) map.addLayer(featuresLayer2);
   document.querySelector("input[name=vm]").disabled = true;

   }
   else {
   if (map.hasLayer(infill)) map.removeLayer(infill);
   if (map.hasLayer(job2)) map.removeLayer(job2);
   if (map.hasLayer(featuresLayer2)) map.removeLayer(featuresLayer2);
   document.querySelector("input[name=vm]").checked = true;
  }
 });

 document.querySelector("input[name=mdu]").addEventListener('change', function() {     //GeoJSON sublayer2
   if(this.checked) {
   if (!map.hasLayer(mdu)) map.addLayer(mdu);
   //if (!map.hasLayer(job2)) map.removeLayer(job2);
   //if (!map.hasLayer(featuresLayer2)) map.addLayer(featuresLayer2);
   //document.querySelector("input[name=vm]").disabled = true;
   }
  else {
if (map.hasLayer(mdu)) map.removeLayer(mdu);
if (map.hasLayer(infill)) map.addLayer(infill);
if (map.hasLayer(job2)) map.removeLayer(job2);
if (map.hasLayer(featuresLayer2)) map.removeLayer(featuresLayer2);
//document.querySelector("input[name=vm]").checked = true;
 }
 });


  map.on('zoomend', function() {
if (map.getZoom() < 9){
if (map.hasLayer(job)) map.removeLayer(job);
if (map.hasLayer(job2)) map.removeLayer(job2);
    if (map.hasLayer(infill)) map.removeLayer(infill);
    if (map.hasLayer(mdu)) map.removeLayer(mdu);
if (map.hasLayer(job3)) map.removeLayer(job3);
  }
  else {
    if (document.querySelector("input[name=cf]").checked && !map.hasLayer(job)) map.addLayer(job);
    if (document.querySelector("input[name=vm]").checked && !map.hasLayer(job2)) map.addLayer(job2);
    if (document.querySelector("input[name=infill]").checked && !map.hasLayer(infill)) map.addLayer(infill);
    if (document.querySelector("input[name=mdu]").checked && !map.hasLayer(infill)) map.addLayer(mdu);
if (document.querySelector("input[name=bt]").checked && !map.hasLayer(job3)) map.addLayer(job3);
  }
});
```

I want to have these layers working. Doesanyone have some ideas how to solve it?

Thanks & Regards

Comment: You don't need to check if map has Layer `!map.hasLayer(job)` you can always add the layer. If the map has already the layer it "overwrites" it, it is the same Object and so it is not add additionaly.

Comment: It doesn't help at all.

I found something here:
https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw/issues/851
But I am far from understanding this

Comment: If you post a fiddle or a Demo, the demo should be working and on the same state / version as you image / problem. And pls Update your fiddle with all paths (script, css, ...), so that it is a working example.

Comment: I have already posted the link to my demo map - this is the code just before the filtering. Code included in Stack Overflow is such an addition.

Answer (score 0):

One reasonable solution is switching off the main geoJSON layer, whereas the another sublayers has been determined.

The simplified code can look like this:

```
 /*  ----------- main GeoJSON Layer job2 made inactive!!! ---------------
job2 = L.geoJson(data2, {  //layer2 Virgin Media start  
    style: style2,
    pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {
            feature.properties.myKey = '<b>'+ feature.properties.Owner + '</b>; ' + feature.properties.Address
            label = String(feature.properties.Owner)
            if (feature.properties.Post_Survey_Home_Count >=100)
        return L.circleMarker(latlng, {
            radius:12,
            opacity: .5,
            //color: "#000",
            color:getColor2(feature.properties.Type),
            fillColor:  getColor2(feature.properties.Type),
            fillOpacity: 0.8
        }).bindTooltip(label, {permanent: false, direction: "top", className: "my-labels"}).openTooltip(); 
           else if (feature.properties.Post_Survey_Home_Count >=50)
           return L.circleMarker(latlng, {
            radius:9,
            opacity: .5,
            //color: "#000",
            color:getColor2(feature.properties.Type),
            fillColor:  getColor2(feature.properties.Type),
            fillOpacity: 0.8
        }).bindTooltip(label, {permanent: false, direction: "top", className: "my-labels"}).openTooltip(); 
            else if (feature.properties.Post_Survey_Home_Count >=1)
            return L.circleMarker(latlng, {
            radius:6,
            opacity: .5,
            //color: "#000",
            color:getColor2(feature.properties.Type),
            fillColor:  getColor2(feature.properties.Type),
            fillOpacity: 0.8
        }).bindTooltip(label, {permanent: false, direction: "top", className: "my-labels"}).openTooltip(); 
            else if (feature.properties.Post_Survey_Home_Count === "")
            return L.circleMarker(latlng, {
            radius:4,
            //opacity: .5,
            //color: "#000",
            color:getColor2(feature.properties.Type),
            fillColor:  getColor2(feature.properties.Type),
            fillOpacity: 0.6,
        }).bindTooltip(label, {permanent: false, direction: "top", className: "my-labels"}).openTooltip(); 
    },
    onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {  // Virgin Media tracker data start ---------
                layer._leaflet_id = feature.properties.Owner;
            var popupContent = "<p><h2>" +
                feature.properties.Owner + "</h2><font color='red'><h3>Status:</font> " +
                feature.properties.Status + "</h3><b> NBU ID:</b> " +
                feature.properties.NBU + "</br><b> Ticket ID:</b> " +
                feature.properties.Ticket_ID + "</br><b> Address (street):</b> " +
                feature.properties.Address + "</br><b> Address (postcode):</b> " +
                feature.properties.Postcode + "</br><b> Asbestos report:</b> " +
                feature.properties.Asbestos_rep + "</br><font color='blue'><b>Planner</b>:</font> " +
                feature.properties.Planner + "</br><font color='blue'><b>Surveyor</b>:</font> " +
                feature.properties.Surveyor + "</br></h2><b>Units provisional:</b> " +
                feature.properties.Client_Home_Count + "</br></h2><b> Post survey units:</b> " +
                feature.properties.Post_Survey_Home_Count + "</br> <b>STATS (applied):</b> " +
                feature.properties.STATS_Applied_for_date + "</br> <b>STATS (completed):</b> " +
                feature.properties.STATS_compleeted + "</br> <b>VM issue date:</b> " +
                feature.properties.Date_issued_from_VM + "</br> <b>QC date:</b> " +
                feature.properties.ACTUAL_Internal_QC_Date + "</br> <b>VM ECD date:</b> " +
                feature.properties.VM_ECD_date + "</br><b>General notes:</b> " +
                feature.properties.General_notes + "</br>" +
                '</br><center><a href="'+ feature.properties.Directory +'" target="_blank">Local directory</a></center></p>' +
                '<center><font color="red"><a href="'+ feature.properties.Sharepoint +'" target="_blank">Sharepoint</a></font></center></p>';                   
            if (feature.properties && feature.properties.popupContent) {
                    popupContent += feature.properties.popupContent;
                }
            layer.bindPopup(popupContent);
            layer.on({ 
                mouseover: function (e) {
                    this.setStyle({
                        'fillColor': '#663300',
                        'weight':11
                    });
                },
                mouseout: function (e) {
                 job2.resetStyle(this);
                }
            }); //layer.on finish
    } //Virgin Media onEachfeature tracker finish
})//.addTo(map);  //layer 2 Virgin Media finish
*/
                    infill = L.geoJson(data2, {    //1st geoJSON sublayer, deriving from the "job"  layer
                        style: style2,
                        pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {
                                feature.properties.myKey = '<b>'+ feature.properties.Owner + '</b>; ' + feature.properties.Address
                                label = String(feature.properties.Owner)
                                if (feature.properties.Post_Survey_Home_Count >=100)
                            return L.circleMarker(latlng, {
                                radius:12,
                                opacity: .5,
                                //color: "#000",
                                color:getColor2(feature.properties.Type),
                                fillColor:  getColor2(feature.properties.Type),
                                fillOpacity: 0.8
                            }).bindTooltip(label, {permanent: false, direction: "top", className: "my-labels"}).openTooltip(); 
                               else if (feature.properties.Post_Survey_Home_Count >=50)
                               return L.circleMarker(latlng, {
                                radius:9,
                                opacity: .5,
                                //color: "#000",
                                color:getColor2(feature.properties.Type),
                                fillColor:  getColor2(feature.properties.Type),
                                fillOpacity: 0.8
                            }).bindTooltip(label, {permanent: false, direction: "top", className: "my-labels"}).openTooltip(); 
                                else if (feature.properties.Post_Survey_Home_Count >=1)
                                return L.circleMarker(latlng, {
                                radius:6,
                                opacity: .5,
                                //color: "#000",
                                color:getColor2(feature.properties.Type),
                                fillColor:  getColor2(feature.properties.Type),
                                fillOpacity: 0.8
                            }).bindTooltip(label, {permanent: false, direction: "top", className: "my-labels"}).openTooltip(); 
                                else if (feature.properties.Post_Survey_Home_Count === "")
                                return L.circleMarker(latlng, {
                                radius:4,
                                //opacity: .5,
                                //color: "#000",
                                color:getColor2(feature.properties.Type),
                                fillColor:  getColor2(feature.properties.Type),
                                fillOpacity: 0.6,
                            }).bindTooltip(label, {permanent: false, direction: "top", className: "my-labels"}).openTooltip(); 
                        },
                            onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
                            layer._leaflet_id = feature.properties.Owner;
                            var popupContent = "<p><h2>" +
                                    feature.properties.Owner + "</h2><font color='red'><h3>Status:</font> " +
                                    feature.properties.Status + "</h3><b> NBU ID:</b> " +
                                    feature.properties.NBU + "</br><b> Ticket ID:</b> " +
                                    feature.properties.Ticket_ID + "</br><b> Address (street):</b> " +
                                    feature.properties.Address + "</br><b> Address (postcode):</b> " +
                                    feature.properties.Postcode + "</br><b> Asbestos report:</b> " +
                                    feature.properties.Asbestos_rep + "</br><font color='blue'><b>Planner</b>:</font> " +
                                    feature.properties.Planner + "</br><font color='blue'><b>Surveyor</b>:</font> " +
                                    feature.properties.Surveyor + "</br></h2><b>Units provisional:</b> " +
                                    feature.properties.Client_Home_Count + "</br></h2><b> Post survey units:</b> " +
                                    feature.properties.Post_Survey_Home_Count + "</br> <b>STATS (applied):</b> " +
                                    feature.properties.STATS_Applied_for_date + "</br> <b>STATS (completed):</b> " +
                                    feature.properties.STATS_compleeted + "</br> <b>VM issue date:</b> " +
                                    feature.properties.Date_issued_from_VM + "</br> <b>QC date:</b> " +
                                    feature.properties.ACTUAL_Internal_QC_Date + "</br> <b>VM ECD date:</b> " +
                                    feature.properties.VM_ECD_date + "</br><b>General notes:</b> " +
                                    feature.properties.General_notes + "</br>" +
                                    '</br><center><a href="'+ feature.properties.Directory +'" target="_blank">Local directory</a></center></p>' +
                                    '<center><font color="red"><a href="'+ feature.properties.Sharepoint +'" target="_blank">Sharepoint</a></font></center></p>';   
                                    if (feature.properties && feature.properties.popupContent) {
                                        popupContent += feature.properties.popupContent;
                                    }
                                    layer.bindPopup(popupContent);
                                    layer.on({ 
                                    mouseover: function (e) {
                                        this.setStyle({
                                            'fillColor': '#663300',
                                            'weight':11
                                        });
                                    },
                                    mouseout: function (e) {
                                     infill.resetStyle(this);
                                    }
                                }); //layer.on finish

                            },
                            filter: function(feature, layer) {   
                                return (feature.properties.Type == "Infill" );
                            }
                            })//.addTo(map);  //Note turned on to start map with Data, Checkbox has checked property.

                    mdu = L.geoJson(data2, {     //2nd geoJSON sublayer, deriving from the "job"  layer
                        style: style2,
                        pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {
                        feature.properties.myKey = '<b>'+ feature.properties.Owner + '</b>; ' + feature.properties.Address
                                label = String(feature.properties.Owner)
                                if (feature.properties.Post_Survey_Home_Count >=100)
                            return L.circleMarker(latlng, {
                                radius:12,
                                opacity: .5,
                                //color: "#000",
                                color:getColor2(feature.properties.Type),
                                fillColor:  getColor2(feature.properties.Type),
                                fillOpacity: 0.8
                            }).bindTooltip(label, {permanent: false, direction: "top", className: "my-labels"}).openTooltip(); 
                               else if (feature.properties.Post_Survey_Home_Count >=50)
                               return L.circleMarker(latlng, {
                                radius:9,
                                opacity: .5,
                                //color: "#000",
                                color:getColor2(feature.properties.Type),
                                fillColor:  getColor2(feature.properties.Type),
                                fillOpacity: 0.8
                            }).bindTooltip(label, {permanent: false, direction: "top", className: "my-labels"}).openTooltip(); 
                                else if (feature.properties.Post_Survey_Home_Count >=1)
                                return L.circleMarker(latlng, {
                                radius:6,
                                opacity: .5,
                                //color: "#000",
                                color:getColor2(feature.properties.Type),
                                fillColor:  getColor2(feature.properties.Type),
                                fillOpacity: 0.8
                            }).bindTooltip(label, {permanent: false, direction: "top", className: "my-labels"}).openTooltip(); 
                                else if (feature.properties.Post_Survey_Home_Count === "")
                                return L.circleMarker(latlng, {
                                radius:4,
                                //opacity: .5,
                                //color: "#000",
                                color:getColor2(feature.properties.Type),
                                fillColor:  getColor2(feature.properties.Type),
                                fillOpacity: 0.6,
                            }).bindTooltip(label, {permanent: false, direction: "top", className: "my-labels"}).openTooltip(); 
                        },
                            onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
                            layer._leaflet_id = feature.properties.Owner;
                                var popupContent = "<p><h2>" +
                                    feature.properties.Owner + "</h2><font color='red'><h3>Status:</font> " +
                                    feature.properties.Status + "</h3><b> NBU ID:</b> " +
                                    feature.properties.NBU + "</br><b> Ticket ID:</b> " +
                                    feature.properties.Ticket_ID + "</br><b> Address (street):</b> " +
                                    feature.properties.Address + "</br><b> Address (postcode):</b> " +
                                    feature.properties.Postcode + "</br><b> Asbestos report:</b> " +
                                    feature.properties.Asbestos_rep + "</br><font color='blue'><b>Planner</b>:</font> " +
                                    feature.properties.Planner + "</br><font color='blue'><b>Surveyor</b>:</font> " +
                                    feature.properties.Surveyor + "</br></h2><b>Units provisional:</b> " +
                                    feature.properties.Client_Home_Count + "</br></h2><b> Post survey units:</b> " +
                                    feature.properties.Post_Survey_Home_Count + "</br> <b>STATS (applied):</b> " +
                                    feature.properties.STATS_Applied_for_date + "</br> <b>STATS (completed):</b> " +
                                    feature.properties.STATS_compleeted + "</br> <b>VM issue date:</b> " +
                                    feature.properties.Date_issued_from_VM + "</br> <b>QC date:</b> " +
                                    feature.properties.ACTUAL_Internal_QC_Date + "</br> <b>VM ECD date:</b> " +
                                    feature.properties.VM_ECD_date + "</br><b>General notes:</b> " +
                                    feature.properties.General_notes + "</br>" +
                                    '</br><center><a href="'+ feature.properties.Directory +'" target="_blank">Local directory</a></center></p>' +
                                    '<center><font color="red"><a href="'+ feature.properties.Sharepoint +'" target="_blank">Sharepoint</a></font></center></p>';           
                                    if (feature.properties && feature.properties.popupContent) {
                                        popupContent += feature.properties.popupContent;
                                    }
                                    layer.bindPopup(popupContent);
                                    layer.on({ 
                                    mouseover: function (e) {
                                        this.setStyle({
                                            'fillColor': '#663300',
                                            'weight':11
                                        });
                                    },
                                    mouseout: function (e) {
                                    mdu.resetStyle(this);
                                    }
                                }); //layer.on finish   
                            },
                            filter: function(feature, layer) {   
                                return (feature.properties.Type == "MDU" );
                            }
                            })//.addTo(map);
```

and afterwards:

```
  document.querySelector("input[name=vm]").addEventListener('change',  function() {
   if(this.checked) {
  //if (!map.hasLayer(job2)) map.addLayer(job2);   - not needed as the job layer is inactive
if (!map.hasLayer(infill)) map.addLayer(infill);
if (!map.hasLayer(mdu)) map.addLayer(mdu);
if (!map.hasLayer(featuresLayer2)) map.addLayer(featuresLayer2);
if (!map.hasLayer(featuresLayer2a)) map.addLayer(featuresLayer2a);
document.querySelector("input[name=infill]").disabled = false;
document.querySelector("input[name=mdu]").disabled = false;
document.querySelector("input[name=infill]").checked = true;
document.querySelector("input[name=mdu]").checked = true;
}
   else {
   //if (map.hasLayer(job2)) map.removeLayer(job2);  - not needed as the job layer is inactive
if (map.hasLayer(infill)) map.removeLayer(infill);
if (map.hasLayer(mdu)) map.removeLayer(mdu);
if (map.hasLayer(featuresLayer2)) map.removeLayer(featuresLayer2);
if (map.hasLayer(featuresLayer2a)) map.removeLayer(featuresLayer2a);
document.querySelector("input[name=infill]").disabled = true;
document.querySelector("input[name=mdu]").disabled = true;
document.querySelector("input[name=infill]").checked = false;
document.querySelector("input[name=mdu]").checked = false;
   }
 });

    document.querySelector("input[name=infill]").addEventListener('change', function() {
    if(this.checked) {
    if (!map.hasLayer(infill)) map.addLayer(infill);
    if (!map.hasLayer(featuresLayer2)) map.addLayer(featuresLayer2);
    }
   else {
   if (map.hasLayer(infill)) map.removeLayer(infill);
   if (map.hasLayer(featuresLayer2)) map.removeLayer(featuresLayer2);
   }
  });

   document.querySelector("input[name=mdu]").addEventListener('change', function() {
   if(this.checked) {
   if (!map.hasLayer(mdu)) map.addLayer(mdu);
   if (!map.hasLayer(featuresLayer2a)) map.addLayer(featuresLayer2a);
   }
   else {
   if (map.hasLayer(mdu)) map.removeLayer(mdu);
   if (map.hasLayer(featuresLayer2a)) map.removeLayer(featuresLayer2a);
  }
 });

This is the one reasonable solution for now, which works. I believe, that we still are able to make the previous combination running.
```