# Leaflet map.RemoveLayer not working - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_removePath' of undefined

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geojson

Regarding to my previous question

[Leaflet checking and disabling GeoJSON sublayers troubleshoots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59144077/leaflet-checking-and-disabling-geojson-sublayers-troubleshoots)

and here

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/343444/leaflet-geojson-sublayers-checked-on-off/

I decided to strip this code away and find, what line particularly causes the problem

```
  (document.querySelector("input[name=infill]").addEventListener('change', function() {
  if (this.checked) map.addLayer(infill);
  else map.removeLayer(infill);
  }))
```

In this event the line  `else map.removeLayer(infill);` causes problem. It means, that something is wrong with `map.removeLayer(infill)`.

Could anybody advise?

Thanks & Regards

Answer (score 1):

Add bellow condition before removing the layer

```javascript
if(map.hasLayer(infill)) {
  map.removeLayer(infill);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to do this a lot, a utility function will help simplify your code, like this:

```
(document.querySelector("input[name=infill]").addEventListener('change', function() {
 switchLayer(infill, this.checked);
}

function switchLayer(layer, state) {
  if (state && !map.hasLayer(layer) {
   map.addLayer(layer);
  }
  else if (!state && map.hasLayer(layer)) {
    map.removeLayer(layer);
  }
}
```